# Visual Studio 2008: How to disable the menu accelerator shortcut or change it?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have VMWare Fusion running Visual Studio 2008 installed on my MacOSX-running MacBook so I decided to remap the wrong keys to be able to get a Mac-based layout in Visual Studio. The remapping was done on VMWare itself.

This way I'm able to, for instance, open brackets with the keys shift+option+7/8.

The problem with this, is that on VS2008 the Alt(option) key is used to highlight a menu. This sometimes gets in the way of the coding or cursor moving process (which I often do with Alt+arrows) when I accidentally am too slow at pressing another key after having already pressed and unpressed Alt.

So, is there any way to disable the menu accelerator or change the key to any other besides Alt?

Answer (score 1):

Use Autohotkey to map the accelerator key to do nothing. It will preempt the visual studio shortcut.